# Should I use "force" or "squeeze" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I want to write the following sentence; it sounds a bit strange to me, but I couldn't find a better way to write it.

> Moreover, having more then one (something) force/squeeze us to take into account (something) in addition to the (something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without further context, I'd have to recommend

> Moreover, having more **than** one (something1) **forces** us to take (something2) into account in addition to (something3).

*Than* is always used in comparisons ("more than one").  The subject phrase ("having more than one X") is treated as singular, because the actual subject is (the act of) *having*, not *more than 1 X*, so we have to use the singular verb form *forces*.

*Force* is clearly the better verb choice than *Squeeze*; squeezing is essentially "to uncomfortably restrict", while forcing is "to impose a requirement."

*Take X into account* vs. *take into account X* is perhaps a more stylistic rather than grammatical choice, but it sounds more natural to me the first way.